# preventing page from refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is the scenario: i have 3 drop down option in my form, i've set first drop down such that it would go to the other page that was selected but its affecting my two other drop downs such that when i select an option the page refresh...below is the java script that i used so the first drop down works...

```
$(function() {

    $("#submit").hide();

    $("#form1 select").change(function() {
        window.location = $("#form1 select option:selected").val();
    })

});
```

is there a way that i can keep this JS and at the same time prevent the page from refreshing whenever i selected an option on the 2 remaining dropdowns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the `<select>` an ID and use that selector instead. Also, you can omit the `option:selected`.

```
$('#id-of-the-select').change(function() {
    window.location = $(this).val();
});
```